# Appcelerator: There are no Android devices connected

Tags: android, configuration, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

**In short:** On Appcelerator I'm getting the message "*There are no Android devices connected*" and I'm not quite sure whether it's a bug or whether I neglected some step in the procedure. I've read everything I can find on the Web and in the Appcelerator help.

**How I got here**: I'm using Windows 8.1, and I'm a self-taught front-end guy who knows a bit of javascript-jquery-html-css-CMS-php.
I was excited to hear about Appcelerator: I was promised that just by using Javascript you can create apps that match the ones written with native SDKs.

**What's the problem:**

- I opened Hello World, got it to run on html, super.
- I downloaded the Android SDK here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK and installed it.
- I have an Android Studio app in my Windows Start menu.
- I connected the Android environment, I have the  Android robot turned green with a check, great.

When I launch Run on Android, I get the message "There are no Android devices connected"

**What I did:**

I went here: https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/160727/there-are-no-android-devices-connected and did as suggested:

- adb kill-server
- adb start-server

Got a message saying server started, but problem persists.

I found something in the help about the Python Windows Installer
I installed python (https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and launched the environment; but could not make out how this related to the problem at hand
In the help (here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Deploying_to_Android_devices) I found a topic called "Deploying to Android devices" but it looks like theire talking about deploying to real Android devices ()For 2.x and 3.x Devices - For 4.x Devices).

I read some people advising to change emulators or to check JRE versions, not sure whether this is relevant.

Comment: You say _found a topic called "Deploying to Android devices" but it looks like theire talking about deploying to real Android devices_. This confuses me. Wasn't that what you wanted? Run on a device? If you want to run on an emulator, use Android Studio to create one: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the device has the debug enabled and that you have enabled your host to deliver? Check if adb can see the device with `adb devices`, if you can see the device here then you can deploy.

Comment: Hi Alberto, 
Thanks for answering! Searched to adb.exe and found multiple occurrences, due to having used Adobe Flash Builder, android-sdk-win platform-tools, etc. Tried adb devices and got an empty list. Any idea what am I supposed to do now? Am I supposed to physically connect an Android device?

Comment: adb devices show you the devices connected, so yes, you need to connect with a cable your physical device; enable the debug mode, connect the device and you will see it.

Comment: I managed to add a device by downloading - launching an android emulator called Genymotion. Now I have an IP address added to the Run menu, and Appcelerator tries to launch: console messages appear. But now after 1minute or so I get a message: saying I should download an SDK API level 23. 
I went managed to open the SDK manager and downloaded everything I could find, rebooted, but error persists. Here is the error message:
ERROR] :  No valid Android SDK targets found.
[ERROR] :  Please download an Android SDK target API level 23 or newer from the Android SDK Manager and try again.

Comment: @AlbertoPastrolin: I have this problem too. I've installed ADB driver for my phone (Vodafone Smart Prime 6), so I've activated Developer modality, I've activated the debug USB mode, I've restarted adb server (with adb kill-server and adb start-server) but the list is empty ;( Where's my fault?

Comment: Have you accepted the RSA request on the phone? If you didn't saw it probably it is a problem with the driver, on windows usually it is recommended to use the koush ones, if they didn't work then you must try another one.